# Какую функцию выполняет этот метод - setSubmitButtonEnabled?

Tags: android

Какую функцию выполняет этот  метод `setSubmitButtonEnabled(true)`  в `SearchView` ?

Он показывает кнопку для старта  начала поиска?

Или что это за кнопка, какую она должна выполнять роль?

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void setSubmitButtonEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

*добавлено в API level 11*

Позволяет показывать иконку поиска, когда запрос не является пустым. Когда текст поиска не пустое и значение `TRUE` показывает иконку поиска. Обычео значение `FALSE` и когда начинаете вводит текст в поиск, иконка теряется. Это функция делает ее всегда видимой.

В случаях, когда `SearchView` используется для фильтрации содержимого текущей деятельности и не запустит отдельный деятельность результаты, то кнопка отправки должна быть отключена.

Comment: Когда текст поиска не пустое  - это как?

Comment: когда в строку поиска что то начали печатать

Comment: Я делал и setSubmitButtonEnabled (true) и  setSubmitButtonEnabled (false)  но все равно, когда я печатаю ничего не меняется. Если она изначально была включена, то она и остается включенной , всегда. Если изначально была выключена, то и изначально такой и остается.

Comment: SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
  
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);  Вот мой код

Comment: @semiromid вам нужно это использовать так. Если нужно показать, делаете TRUE, если не нужно, делаете FALSE. Событие обрабатываете сами

Comment: Понятно,спасибо. Странные разработчики, неужели нельзя это было сделать им, а точнее два варианта использования этой кнопки.